# Problem with SEF URL For K2 Users/Authors

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

I'm having trouble setting up proper SEF URL's for the users / authors on a site I'm working on. I have "Enable advanced SEF for K2 URLs" on, and everything works fine as long I can associate a menu item with (categories, etc). The site I'm working on has MANY different contributors and creating a menu item for each author seems like its probably not the right way to go about it.

Currently, if I view a user from the "homepage" from a module, K2 prefixes component/k2 before author like this: mysite.com/component/k2/author/authorname

If I view a user from within the category view, K2 prefixes the category name like this: mysite.com/categoryname/author/authorname

Ideally, what I'd like to have is this: mysite.com/author/authorname

Is there any way to accomplish this without creating a menu item for each author? or doing something funky with .htaccess?

I would greatly appreciate any help concerning this, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- make a k2-Menu-Item of Type "Categories" without adding a Category. Call alias i.e. "detail".
- append Menu-Item to an hidden Menu (means: not used in an Module)
- set k2-Options "Advanced > Advanced SEF Settings" Author-Prefix like "profil"

this will catch orphan Categories, Authors, Tags in an url like:

Author: yourHomepage/detail/profil/222-authorname
Categorie: yourHomepage/detail/your-category-prefix/id-nr-of-category/alias
Tag: yourHomepage/detail/your-tag-prefix/tag

Regards